# Rails: form_for doesn't turn parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post

I'm basically trying to create a Rails **form_for** but it simply does not turn parameters. I've checked the server log and it receives the parameter but cannot capture on the create function. I'm watching **andrewperk**'s tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unq1yubL6lQ) about **create** and **save** methods. What could I possible done wrong?. Here is my Users controller;

```
 def new
    @user=User.new
  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.blank?
      render :new
    else
      @user.save
      render :index
    end
  end
```

And here is my form;

```
<h1>Add an available user</h1>

    <%= form_for @user do |a| %>
        <p>
            <%= a.label :name %>
            <%= a.text_field :name %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= a.label :surname %>
            <%= a.text_field :surname %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= a.submit "Add new available user"%>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: params[:user] is correct

Answer (score 2):

You should use `params[:user]` in your controller, because this is how the HTML form fields are named by default (you can check page source).

Also I'd suggest refactoring the `create` method a bit. It is a convention that you redirect to index page instead of just rendering it after creating a record.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have mistyped. I already have the user as params[:user]

Comment: You could, if you wanted to be super-fancy, use "respond_with" to clean this up even more :)